# I'd like to select an arbitrary date from Oracle

Tags: oracle, business-objects

Everyone knows you can do SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL to get a single row representing today's date.

I'd like to do something similar, but it would look like:

SELECT MAGICDATE FROM DUAL 
WHERE MAGICDATE = *Prompted in the application software*

Bit of a long story why...
I'm using a package called SAP Business Objects. It translates user queries into SQL and can get a little tricky. I would like to pull out the user prompts into separate little sub-queries, then use the results of the prompts to power my main queries.

The queries look like:

select user_id, test_centre, test_date, count(*)
from
*Lots of tables*
where user_id in *Prompted User Id* 
and test_centre in *Prompted test_centre*
and test_date between *Prompted Date 1* and *Prompted Date 2*

Comment: Are you after an arbitrary date or an arbitrary date + time?

Comment: "Prompted in the application software" is a bit unclear. Normally you prompt in the application and the user-entered value is assigned to a bind variable. Your SQL queries use bind variables, which are assigned in this manner at runtime. If, for example, the input can only be a string and you must convert to date, then something like what you are asking for makes sense, but it would include TO_DATE() and the bind variable in the SELECT, not directly the user input.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) + dbms_random.value(-5000, 5000) random_date,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) + floor(dbms_random.value(-5000, 5000)) random_datetime
FROM dual;
```

I've provided ways to get both a random date and a random date + time. Note that I've used TRUNC(SYSDATE) as the seed date and range of 5000 days before and after. You may wish to change the seed date so that it's SYSDATE or even a fixed date, as well as to amend the date ranges as per your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Boneist, it's not a *random* date I'm after, more allowing the user to specify any old date.

Comment: Ah, ok; in which case, can't SAP handle bind variables? If so, then `select :date_variable from dual` (if you can only pass a string as the bind variable, you will need to explicitly convert it, e.g `to_date(:date_variable, '<date format mask>)`).

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do this?

```
select to_date([prompted_date],'someformat') from dual
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, I may need the date conversion, but the application software may already get me to a date rather than the string representation. Will try things out and see.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer to your question is:

```
select @prompt(.....) from dual
```

But I don't think that is actually what you're looking for.  Can you be more specific about what you are attempting to do?

Comment: Actually Joe I think that's just what I want! 
The prompt functionality will give the user the ability to select dates nicely in Business Objects, the resulting date can be reused in many different queries.

Comment: Well, you can re-use a prompt in several queries just by using the same syntax in each.  That is, if you have the same `@prompt(...)` in multiple queries, the prompt will only appear once.  That's why I asked what you were trying to do :)

Comment: Rapidly coming to the conclusion that my idea is just a painful distraction and good old @prompt will have to do!